# Someone just downvoted my answer and question without any reason

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Recently, I noticed that someone just downvoted one answer and question of mine in a short period of time without any comments. I suspect a possible hater. What should I do? I have asked for clarification but have not received anything till now. Even before I have had such cases.
If it would have been an obvious reason for downvoting then many people would have commented or downvoted. But no one did.

Here, is the proof:
[image]

Comment: This can be frustrating. I've had it happen too. I try not to worry about it too much. As a devil's advocate position,... Your two questions were posted on April 6 & 8. Assume a single voter for both. (1) Is it possible the voter was reviewing multiple posts over the last several days as a batch and both your posts were reviewed?  or (2) Is it possible these votes were from multiple people?  Seems like there are a lot of ways this could have happened legitimately.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan I understand that it could be by the same people or different. The point is that why don't they post any comment suggesting any improvements if they think that's a bad post. I'm not saying that my post is always correct and useful. In all three downvotes, no comments were made. It would make sense if others would have downvoted as well but no one did. So what special did they find? People like these should be sent warning messages imo. As suggested in the linked answer should I flag my post for mods?

Comment: There are mountains of pages on SE Meta sites about how there is no requirement to comment on downvotes. Suggestions for improvement are not required. Such a requirement could set off revenge downvoting too.  The tooltip (hover mouse over the down vote arrow) already provides the comment.  Some people leave comments. Some don't.  Personally I try not to worry about it too much (though I understand it can be frustrating).